# %0A in text passed to JavaScript causes unterminated string literal

Tags: javascript

When i call:

call('%0D%0ASometext');

I get error:

unterminated string literal

I get the string '%0D%0ASometext' from PHP - it's string entered by user. So is there any way to pass this text to JS function without errors and without removing any info from it?

Comment: What's in the body of `call`? This wouldn't be in a PHP template, would it? If so, what does the rendered JS look like on the client side?

Comment: What is this «call»?  If you feed this string to `parseInt` or `String` you won't get this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

`call(decodeURIComponent('%0D%0ASometext'));`

Comment: Now that's *definitely* an unterminated string literal ;-) Also, you have one too many closing parentheses.